# Maven Local Repository, Two machines and Git: missing artifact

Tags: java, git, maven, opencv

I am building a Java project using Maven. Since I need to add one jar file that has not been deployed on the central Maven repository (OpenCV), I created on the first machine, named `M1`, a local repository and deployed (`mvn deploy:deploy-file`) the external jar `lib.jar` file into that repository.

In the project `pom.xml` file I added the following lines:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
   <id>in-project</id>
   <name>In Project Repo</name>
   <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

On machine `M1` everything is fine.

I use `git` both for versioning and for syncing two development environments on two different machines, `M1` and `M2` (I do not think it's relevant, but `M1` has OS X and `M2` has linux).

However, after a `git pull` on `M2`, if I run maven on `M2` I get an error message caused by the missing artifact `lib.jar` from the local repo.

`M1` has maven 3.2.2, `M2` has maven 3.0.4.

Is there any way to move local repositories using git or another software?

Thanks.

Comment: btw, you will probably have to copy opencv_java.so, too !

Comment: It is among the project resources.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to create a remote repo, not local repo:

- setup a Sonatype Nexus or Jfrog Artifactory instance
- upload your jar into it
- edit your settings.xml file to mirror it

That will allow any maven build you run to retrieve the jar regardless of machine.